# Не могу подключить расширения в php.ini

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Установлен сервер Apache 2.2, PHP 5, MySQL Server 5.5. PHP прикручен к Apache. MySQL не прикручен к PHP.

Как в php.ini подключить следующие расширения:

- `php_pdo.dll`
- `php_pdo_mysql.dll`
- `php_mysql.dll` (удаление " ; " перед соответствующими строчками в этом файле результата не даёт)?

Все расширения присутствуют в папке `\ext\`. Что делать? Раскомментировать - раскомментировал, а всё равно не работает.

Comment: Apache перезагружал, что в логах пишется?

Comment: Серверу рестарт делал. А где логи посмотреть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Директива extension_dir точно указывает на директорию, в которой у Вас лежат расширения?

Веб-сервер/php-fpm перезапускали после редактирования php.ini?

Файл php.ini точно тот самый, который использует РНР? Консольная и веб-версии РНР могут использовать разные файлы php.ini. В веб-версии используемый файл можно посмотреть через phpinfo(), в консольной - `php -i`

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел, там была не та директория ("./" вместо "ext/"). Исправил. Всё равно то же самое.

Comment: Попробуйте указать полный путь:

extension_dir = "c:/php/ext"

В PHPIniDir у Вас что?

Comment: это в httpd.conf:<br>
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php5/php5apache2_2.dll"<br>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php<br>
PHPIniDir "C:/php5/"<br>
в php.ini поставил:<br>
extension_dir = "c:/php/ext/"<br>
теперь уже говорит, что не может найти эти расширения. Но они там есть! что делать? (кстати, я поставил PHP 5.3)

Comment: И правильно говорит. В PHPIniDir Вы указываете, что php у Вас в директории "C:/php5/", а расширения ищите в "c:/php/ext/". Исправьте на extension_dir = "C:/php5/ext/" - ведь расширения у Вас там лежат?

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: не могли бы Вы ещё подсказать, как ПОЛНОСТЬЮ удалить базу MySQL, потому что я её переустанавливал, теперь на порту 3306 она не работает (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)), на 3309 выдает ошибку: <br>Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение. in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\mod4\createdb.php on line 8
Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение. <br> что делать?

Comment: Попробуйте без пароля подключаться, по дефолту вроде как у рута пустой пароль.

Answer (score 1):

1) открываем php.ini;
2) находим следующее:

```
; On windows:
extension_dir ="C:\Путь\К\php\ext"
```

(соответственно проверить наличие файлов php_pdo.dll, php_pdo_mysql.dll, php_mysql.dll в директории ext)

3) далее в этом же файле находим:

```
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
extension=php_bz2.dll
```

4) прописываем файлы, или раскоментируем их (удалив ";" перед нужной строкой)

```
extension=php_pdo.dll  
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

5) перезагружаем вэбсервер, профит!

Answer (score -1):

Скорей всего, при установке MySQL на шаге "MySQL Server Instance Configuration" Вы не задали пароль root'а. Соответственно, попробуйте войти с пустым паролем.