# Как полностью удалить MySQL сервер с компьютера?

Tags: windows, mysql

Сначала были такие [проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/20196/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-php-ini). Теперь у меня неразбериха с учётными записями в MySQL. Как ПОЛНОСТЬЮ удалить MySQL сервер? При удалении через "Установка и удаление программ" учётные записи остаются. Как удалить всё: и программу, и учётные записи, и порты освободить? Как будто MySQL Server и не стоял у меня? (У меня Windows XP SP3.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Удаляем MySQL через "Установка и удаление программ"
2. Удаляем папку, в которую был установлен MySQL: "C:Program FilesMySQL"
3. Ищем в "C:Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/" папку MySQL и удаляем её.
4. Перезагружаемся